# jQuery Graph (of nodes) visulisation heat map

Tags: jquery, graph, graph-visualization

Does anyone know of a jQuery library that does graph visualizations but allows you to set the size of the nodes. I would like to use this to represent the amount of errors showing at a collection of different systems.

Example Data (where right/below = child):

```
(25) -> (100) -> (1)
              -> (500)
```

Diagram:

[image]

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Im quite sure it can be done using http://raphaeljs.com/ but its pure javascript library using svg

Comment: I don't know if this would be at all interesting to you: [ImageMapper jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster). There are some questions about using it here on SO, or [here for code samples](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my recent research into a similar need, I have three good leads, but none are JQuery plugins (although one could make them into a plugin). They are all side-by-side compatible with JQuery though...

1. [mermaid](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid)
2. [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org)
3. [vis.js](http://visjs.org)

Mermaid is simple, and you may like the graph description syntax (like the old ATT/Bell Labs 'dot' language), but it might not place nodes (exactly) where you want them to be.

Both Cytoscape.js and Vis.js are great, easy to use and powerful. One difference between them is, Cytoscape.js renders to a canvas, whereas vis.s renders to SVG.
There is a quick demo of vis.js that [interprets the dot language.](http://visjs.org/examples/network/15_dot_language_playground.html)